# Is this a bad practice in Typescript? What are my options?

Tags: typescript, singleton, static-classes

I want to have a consistent instance of a class (a collection in this example) to work in the whole project with.
I am using Typescript so I want to work around the concept of creating some wonky object in the JavaScript-style without any type safety.

As I don't need to pass a real object of this class anywhere, I am completely fine with the idea of having a class with only static members, which I can access in the project by calling the class name.
Is there anything wrong with this concept?
Should I use a singleton pattern and then just do `export Collection.getInstance()` at the end of the file?

```
export class CollectionInstance{
  static readonly exampleCollection = new ExampleCollection();

  //noinspection JSUnusedLocalSymbols
  private constructor() {
  }

  public static load(){

  }

  public static get(key: string){

  }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite see how `Collection.getInstance()` fits in with the rest of your code, nor am I sure what you are doing with `get()`, `load()`, etc. Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NrKdom) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: I suspect you don't need `class` at all in this code to get the functionality you want with type safety, but without a [mre] it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: I agree with jcalz, its hard to see what your doing but I believe you should just be able to get away with a const.

`export const Collection = new ExampleCollection();` ? and then just import collection when needed and use it.